# How to trigger the same button to increment and decrement the counter by 1?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that increment a counter by 1 on onclick event.

```
     <div class="detail-banner-btn heart">
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> 
        <span data-toggle="I Love It"> 
            <a onclick="like()"> Give Heart </a>
        </span>
     </div>
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <strong id="totalLikes" > 0 </strong>  people love it

    <script>
     function like() {
      var a = document.getElementById("totalLikes").innerHTML = +1;
     }
     </script>
```

I want the number to be increment by 1 at first click and on second click it needs to be decremented by 1 and so on.

Comment: You can't achieve this unless you know on what basis you need to decrement. You need to have another button click so that you'd know that you need to decrement.

Comment: How will the button whether to increment or to decrement?

Comment: At first it needs to increment by one and after that decrement

Answer (score 2):

Try following code

```
<div class="detail-banner-btn heart">
 <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> <span data-toggle="I Love It"> <a onclick="like()"> Give Heart </a></span>
 </div>

    <script>
var isLiked=false;
var a=0;
 function like()
  {
  isLiked=!isLiked;
  if(isLiked) {
    a = document.getElementById("totalLikes").innerHTML = parseInt(a)+1;
  }
  else {

  a = document.getElementById("totalLikes").innerHTML = parseInt(a)-1;
  }

  }
 </script>

 <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <strong id="totalLikes" > 0 </strong>  people love it
```

Comment: after two times click the value is -1 

Comment: @markharringson plz check I have just updated the answer

Comment: thanks buddy, but it does'nt increment again on third click

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have a like button, a comment button, and an area for likes, such as the code below:

```
<a href="#" id="like-btn" class="card-link">
      <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="card-link">
      <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
</a>
<p>Likes <span>0</span></p>
```

It would make sense to use jQuery here, and simply update the likes by setting a counter in the JavaScript section of your code (or in a separate file). This way, you don't have to convert the counter to an integer (or number type in JavaScript), or any of that. This is where jQuery makes things much more simple.

```
var likes = 0;
$('#like-btn').on('click', function() {
    if(likes % 2 === 0) {
        likes++;
        $('span').text(likes);
    }
    else {
        likes--;
        $('span').text(likes);
    }
});
```

This why you can just increment the number of likes in a more simple way. If the number has no remainder after being divided by 2, you know it is even, and needs to be incremented (and will increment on your first click), otherwise it will be deincremented.

Comment: This is not what i am trying to achieve, please read the question carefully